# MLE for an undirected network degree distribution

Tags: maximum-likelihood, network

I have an empirical undirected network. I assume, that a degree distribution is $ F(k) = 1 - e^{1 - \frac{k}{m}} $. and would like to estimate $m$.

The only method I'm aware of for such task is MLE.

If I write a likelihood function $ L = \prod_{i=1}^{N}{p(x_i)} $ (where  $ p(k) =  \frac{1}{m}e^{1 - \frac{k}{m}} $ and ${x_i}$ is a degree of node $i$), then I can estimate $ m = \bar{x} $, but as I see the result is twice as much as it should be.

I believe this is because I should not write the likelihood function as I did, because degrees of two connected vertices are not independent, so I should take this into account, but I don't quite undestand how can I do this.

Could you confirm or reject this, and if I am right, please could you help me to build the correct likelihood function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the support of the variable is not $(0;\infty)$ but it is $k \in [m;\infty)$, I suppose (you didn't say where the variable is defined).

So your density is this (I prefer to indicate $x$ the variable instead of $k$)

$f(x,m)=\frac{1}{m}e^{1-\frac{x}{m}}\mathbb{1}_{[m;\infty)}(x)$

and, I suppose, $m >0$

Now, as you can see, the support depends on the parameter. Are you able to continue by yourself?

EDIT: anyway...here is the solution

The likelyhood is the following

$L(m)=\frac{1}{m^n}e^{n-\frac{\sum_{i}x_i}{m}}\mathbb{1}_{(0;x_{(1)}]}(m)$

so the MLE estimator is

$\hat{m}=min[x_{(1)};\bar{x}]=x_{(1)}$

where $x_{(1)}=min(x)$

Comment: Excuse me, I should've mentioned that the minimum degree in the graph is $m > 0$. So, the density you suggested is the same as I used (at least, in the product in a likelihood function): $f(x,m)=\frac{1}{m}e^{1-\frac{x}{m}}1_{[m;\inf]}(x) = \frac{1}{m}e^{1-\frac{x}{m}}$ because there is no observation $x_i < m$. Did I get something wrong?

Comment: it is not the same because in my density the support depends on $m$. If you do the calculation you will see that the MLE estimator is $\hat{\omega}=min(x)$

Comment: I edited my answer with calculations. I hope it helps

Comment: Ohh, I see.. $\bar{x}$ cannot be the maximum, because there are $x_i < \bar{x}$ and L becomes zero, then. Should've paid more attention to that indicator function... Thank you very much, you really helped!